# Pulse Shaping use in OFDM

Tags: matlab

can I use pulse shaping and cyclic prefix simultaneously for OFDM and SC-OFDM? If so, in which sequence? Also, what should be the symbols per second for pulse shaping filter, e.g., SRRC?

I tried to insert raised cosine pulse shaping after cyclic prefix in transmitter, but it greatly degrades the bit error rate. I am not sure if there's mistake in the code or is the process I am following is wrong?

Comment: by 'cyclic prefix' do you mean 'cyclic redundancy check' on each transmitted block? 3GPP TR 25.141 V7.0.0 does no have the term Cyclic Prefix, but it has CRC.

Comment: Or by 'cyclic prefix' do you mean Guard Interval?

Comment: I do not understand when you say you implemented pulse shapping AFTER CRC: you generate your transport stream, 0s and 1s, then you get to symbols, and then you apply pulse shapes, but the pulse shape is defined aside of whatever contents in transport stream.